# how to convert files to bits or hex in R language

Tags: r, binary, hex

My question is
How I can read any file in R language and represent it as hex or binary value

For example I wana read samll pdf and present it in bit's or binary or hex

Comment: You can read an entire file as a "raw" byte vector with `readBinary <- function(filepath)readBin(filepath, "raw", file.info(filepath)$size))`. It's not clear to me exactly how you want to "present it" but there are plenty of functions for formatting raw data in R.

Comment: ok it's present it in hex but if I want it like 0010

Comment: So what input would result in `0010`? Maybe the `rawToBits()` function will help you. It's hard to guess without any sort of concrete example.